# Gradle apply from file on classpath?

Tags: java, gradle, build-process

Is it possible to package gradle scripts in a jar and the reference it from the buildscript section?

I want to do something like this:

```
buildscript {
   dependencies {
      classpath 'my.gradle:my-gradle:1.0-SNAPSHOT'
   }
}

apply from: 'my/gradle/java-defaults.gradle'
```

I know I can use `apply from:` with an url, but that requires me to setup a webserver.

Comment: maybe what you need is a custom Gradle plugin instead of packaging the scripts in a jar as they are.

Comment: I asked the same Q, you can see the answer here - 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9539986/how-to-share-a-common-build-gradle-via-a-repository

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Matt pointed out, this question is already answered: [How to share a common build.gradle via a repository?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9539986/how-to-share-a-common-build-gradle-via-a-repository).

I will try implement a plugin (option 2) that does the default configurations.