# how to create gradle buildscript configuration

Tags: gradle

How to create gradle buildscript configuration?

The following gives me:
"> Could not find method gradleCommon() for arguments [com.example:artefact:1.0.0] on org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler_Decorated@5aaf4b6e.":

```
buildscript {
    configurations {
        gradleCommon
    }

    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        gradleCommon 'com.example:artefact:1.0.0'
        classpath 'com.bmuschko:gradle-tomcat-plugin:2.0'
        classpath 'mysql:mysql-connector-java:5.1.27'
    }
}
```

Comment: Try a different name, as it may be conflicting with [Project#getGradle()](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/Project.html#getGradle()) which is implicitly in the environment.

Comment: It's not clear to me why you need to create a `configuraton` inside the `buildscript` closure. That's usually not necessary. The `buildscript` only configures Gradle, anyway, so it would seem redundant, unless you were planning to use the `configuration` elsewhere.

Comment: @BenManes I edited my answer, I tried gradleCommon and gradleDep1337 and both did not work. I doubt it is because of a naming conflict.

Comment: @Jolta I was trying to use Matt's answer from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9539986/how-to-share-a-common-build-gradle-via-a-repository while having extra buildscript dependencies.

Comment: This is a bug, please post it on the [Gradle forum](https://discuss.gradle.org). If you add `println configurations` you'll see that yours was not added .However using `configurations.create('gradleCommon')` instead works.

Comment: Here is a link to the bug report on gradle forum I created: https://discuss.gradle.org/t/bug-creating-buildscript-configuration/10481

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will need to use the API as documented to create a buildscript configuration. The behavior you are seeing is a combination of trying to call a non-existent method and Groovy's missing method behavior being invoked.

From my response on the Gradle Forums:

> The buildscript block is associted with the ScriptHandler interface. If you look at the javadoc, you'll see that 'repositories' and 'dependencies' are the only supported closures. There is a getConfigurations(), but no configurations(Closure configureClosure), which is why configurations.create(...) would work, but configurations { } definitely would not.

From the response on the Gradle Forums by Mark Vieira:

> What's actually happening here is when you call configurations(Closure configureClosure) inside the buildscript { } block it is actually calling the method on the Project object since Groovy will continue searching up the closure scope until it finds a match.