# Storing Gradle configuration common to multiple projects

Tags: gradle

I have a few projects in separate git repositories.
Is there a way to store common gradle configuration that they are using in one place?

The common configuration includes repositories, tasks etc.

Comment: After some additional searching I found that similar question was already answered here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9539986/how-to-share-a-common-build-gradle-via-a-repository

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it's possible. You can define a gradle file with all the necessary data and expose it, e.g. www.company.com/master.gradle.

Then apply it in the following way:

```
apply from: 'www.company.com/master.gradle'
```

in all gradle scripts that require these global settings. [This](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/init_scripts.html) link may be also useful.

Comment: Is it possible to publish master.gradle configuration the same way you can publish pom.xml? I want to use some versioning mechanism for it and simply sharing file via http server does not allow it.

Comment: @Sergey, not sure. Can't test it as well :/