# Android gradle error: package does not exist

Tags: java, android, maven, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

First of I should say that I install Android Studio 2.1.2 on my machine
and build and run "hello world android" without problem.

At now I'm trying to build https://github.com/osmdroid/osmdroid ,
according to instruction https://github.com/osmdroid/osmdroid/wiki/How-to-build-osmdroid-from-source I just need type:
`gradle clean build`

I type and got bunch of error about not existing tools 23.0.2,
so I replace  `buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"` in `build.gradle` with
`buildToolsVersion "24.0.0"`, because of `Android Studio` `SDK Manager` have 
many versions of `SDK Platforms`, but only one version of `Android SDK Platform-Tools`, and this is not `23.0.2`.

**1) Is it right solution? Why even authors of osmdroid specify version of tools?**

There are also bunch of links to web via `apply from: https://`,
so I have to download and replace link from `https://` to `file://`,
but after that it fails with error:

```
error: package com.google.android.maps does not exist
import com.google.android.maps.MapView;
```

I installed all version of SDK Platforms from 7 to 24,
but still get error.

**2) How should I fix it?**

May be `gradle` is just alpha quality software and I should use maven?
I used `gradle`, because of it looks like used by `Android Studio`.

**Update**

I fixed **2**, the problem was in line

> compileSdkVersion 'Google Inc.:Google APIs:23'
>   in `build.gradle` file, which I commented before, and forgot to uncomment after.

But **1** is still valid.

Comment: Sounds like you're missing Android SDK's Google's maven Repository dependency... you can launch the standalone update manager to download ... or do it using your terminal

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you're missing gradle dependencies.

Try installing the **google's maven repository** and **google play services lib**.

You can install it using the Android SDK's update channel manager graphic interface:

[image: google play services]

or using your terminal if you have Android exported in your PATH like this:

```
android update sdk --filter extra-google-m2repository --no-ui --force -a
```

Also try using gradle wrapper, by `./gradlew` on *nix systems or `start gradlew.bat` on Windows because it will download and run the right gradle version.

To understand about `apply` and plugins check the official [documentation](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/plugins.html) and this [SO question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9539986/how-to-share-a-common-build-gradle-via-a-repository).

Comment: No, I have `~/Android/Sdk/extras/google/m2repository`, may be I need some environment variable, like `ANDROID_HOME`?

Comment: Thanks, `android update sdk...` not help at all, but `./gradlew` solves problem for me.

Comment: No, I thouhgt that `./gradlew` solved problem by mistake, if run not `./gradlew` (which successful), but `./gradlew build` I got the same  error.

Comment: @user1244932 have you installed google play services lib?

Comment: I have no idea what is google play services **lib**, but I install all `SDK Tools` with `Google`  in their names via Android Studio before I post question.

Comment: Yep, I installed all stuff on your screenshot with "Google" in it's name.

Comment: And I have bunch of maps.jar (different versions), that match `grep com.google.android.maps.MapView`, so the problem is where `gradle` trying to find them.

Comment: I fixed **second** question, but **the first on** remains.