# Utilize ant in settings.gradle during configuration phase

Tags: gradle, groovy, jar

I want to apply a shared gradle file to my projects `settings.gradle`. The shared file is located in a `jar` which must be downloaded and extracted during the configuration phase. This is because is applies a plugin which must be applied in the configuration phase. I found this related question: [How to share a common build.gradle via a repository?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9539986/987860) My preferred way is described in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39228611/987860

However, this appears to be working in `build.gradle` only. I tried to move the `buildscript` block to my `settings.gradle`.

**settings.gradle**

```
buildscript {

    ext {
        dependencyVersion = '0.1.2'
    }

    repositories {
        maven {
            credentials {
                username 'user'
                password 'password'
            }
            url 'https://my-private-maven-repo.com'
        }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "my.group:myartifact:$dependencyVersion"
    }
    dependencies {
        def gradleScripts = new File(rootDir, '/build/gradle')
        delete gradleScripts
        def jars = configurations.classpath.files as List<File>
        ant.unjar(src: jars.find { it.name.matches '.*myartifact.*' }, dest: gradleScripts) {
            patternset {
                include(name:'*.gradle')
            }
        }
    }
}

apply from: new File(rootDir, '/build/gradle/myscript.gradle')
```

But this results in the following exception:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Settings file 'settings.gradle' line: 24

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating settings 'journal'.
> Could not get unknown property 'ant' for object of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 0.019 secs
Could not get unknown property 'ant' for object of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler.
```

Is there any way to utilize `ant` int the confiuration phase before my `settings.gradle` is evaluated? I need to have the dependency downloaded and extractet before the to-be-downloaded file gets applied.

Answer (score 0):

This is a really unusual way to do things. I'd really recommend not doing what you're trying to do because it'll make your build much slower than it should be. You're deleting `build/gradle` and extracting the contents of the plugin's jar on every build.

Everything inside a `build.gradle` (or `settings.gradle`) can be put into a plugin and distributed that way. You already have a jar that needs to be downloaded, so converting `myscript.gradle` into a plugin is very easy to roughly convert.

Put this in `src/main/groovy/some/package/MyPlugin.groovy` in the project that's producing the plugin jar already:

```
package some.package

import org.gradle.api.*

class MyPlugin implements Plugin<Project> {
   void apply(Project project) {
      project.with {
        // contents of script
      }
   }
}
```

For plugins applied to `settings.gradle`:

```
package some.package

import org.gradle.api.*

class MyPlugin implements Plugin<Settings> {
   void apply(Settings settings) {
      settings.with {
        // contents of script
      }
   }
}
```

Then you can just add the dependency to the plugin and use `apply plugin: some.package.MyPlugin`.

There are a lot of other advantages of developing/distributing plugins in this way. You can find more information on plugin development in the [Gradle Guides](https://gradle.org/guides/).

Alternatively, if you absolutely must keep the separate `.gradle` script.  If you can serve it separately (outside of the jar), you can do:

`apply from: "http://example.com/some/url/myscript.gradle"`

The downside with this is that it'll download the file on every build (this is fixed in Gradle 4.2).

Comment: Thanks, I haven't noticed a significant increase in build time. So downloading and extracting a jar isn't a major problem, I don't mind if it's done on every build. What my script does is it simply applies a plugin from the official gradle plugin repo but i don't wanna copy/paste the content to all my projects. Unless there is no way in unjar'ing the downloaded file I would want to keep it as is. Applying the configuration from a publicly available url might be the last but a doable option.