# Gradle : Something like Maven Parent POM

Tags: gradle, parent-pom

In our company, many of the different projects use similar technology stack and will have many common features.
So, we want to maintain the common features, dependencies etc. in one common file and refer it in the other projects. 
In maven, it is something like creating a separate maven project with the common dependency information and refer that in the other projects as .

I want to do something similar to the maven parent project in gradle, which can be used by all different projects.
I googled for that, but could not find a concise information on how to do that.
We are not allowed to use external thirdparty plugins.

It would be great if someone could explain it how to do that.

Comment: I found the best solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9539986/how-to-share-a-common-build-gradle-via-a-repository

Answer (score 1):

in gradle you can do that, but for it you need to have external plugin, otherwise it is not possible at least for now. I have achieved it in this way:

```
buildscript {
repositories { jcenter() }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.netflix.nebula:nebula-dependency-recommender:4.3.0'
    }
}

allprojects {
    apply plugin: 'nebula.dependency-recommender'
    apply plugin: 'groovy'
    apply plugin: 'java'

    sourceCompatibility = 1.8
    targetCompatibility = 1.8

    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        jcenter()

        maven { url "http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/" }
        maven { url "REPOSITORY_OF_YOUR_PARENT_POM.XML" }
    }

    dependencyRecommendations {
        mavenBom module: 'YOUR_PARENT_POM_GROUP:YOUR_PARENT_POM_ID:YOUR_PARENT_POM_VERSION'
    }
}
```

where:

REPOSITORY_OF_YOUR_PARENT_POM.XML - any system like nexus or something else accessible for maven

YOUR_PARENT_POM_GROUP - your parent pom project group (e.g. com.foo.bar.parent)

YOUR_PARENT_POM_ID - your parent pom id (e.g. projects-parent)

YOUR_PARENT_POM_VERSION - your parent pom project version (e.g. 1.0.1)

so, if the external dependency to netflix.nebula is fine , than you can go in this way

Answer (score 0):

Gradle has many extension mechanisms for leveraging build logic located outside of the main script.

A simple thing that can be done is to use an external build script, which can be sourced from the local file system or through an URL, see the [documentation on this topic](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/organizing_build_logic.html#sec:configuring_using_external_script).

If that solution gets too problematic, then you can move to packaging a real plugin that others can apply and potentially configure.

This will allow you to configure much more than dependencies for example.