# How can i publish just a build script in gradle?

Tags: gradle, build.gradle

I want to publish a common build script which i will include across various projects in my application.

This will contain only the common set of dependencies, i.e dependencies with particular versions that will be common across all the artifacts in my enterprise application..

My applications will refer to this file from the url.

How can i achieve this?

EDIT1: my exploration in this direction is based on this answer on SO:
[How to share a common build.gradle via a repository?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9539986/how-to-share-a-common-build-gradle-via-a-repository)

Comment: So you want to share dependencies across multiple projects with no need for downloading? or just share the same set of dependencies with no need to declare them at a child project?

Comment: I want the build file to be published to the repository. Going forward, all my spring boot applications will simply refer to this script from the url.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few different options for this.

- One is to publish a project with the dependencies you want to share defined as [API dependencies](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/java_library_plugin.html#sec:java_library_separation). Projects that depend on this will inherit the dependencies.
- Or you could write and publish a Gradle plugin that will [configure your projects with the common dependencies](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/implementing_gradle_plugins.html#reacting_to_plugins). Projects can apply the plugin, and will automatically be configured in a certain way. (You don't need to publish a plugin to do this - first try creating a project-local [buildSrc convention plugin](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/organizing_gradle_projects.html#sec:build_sources).)

I would actually recommend neither of these approaches.

- It's easy to get into a tangled web of dependency hell when transitive dependencies are inherited. It's likely that at some point some dependency will clash, and excluding dependencies can be a *big* headache, and will easily cancel out any benefit in trying to reduce a little duplication.
- Additionally, it's nice when a project is explicit about its dependencies. Being able to look at a `build.gradle.kts` and understand exactly what dependencies are set is very convenient.

Instead, what I would recommend is controlling the *versions* of common dependencies in a central location. This can be achieved with the [Java Platform plugin](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/java_platform_plugin.html#java_platform_plugin). This plugin can be applied to a single `build.gradle.kts` file, and it lists all versions of all possible dependencies. (It can also [import existing Maven BOMs](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/java_platform_plugin.html#sec:java_platform_bom_import), like the Spring Boot BOM).

Now, all subprojects can [add a platform dependency](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/java_platform_plugin.html#sec:java_platform_consumption) on the 'Java Platform' project.

```kotlin
dependencies {
  // import the platform from a Maven repo
  implementation(platform("my.company:my-shared-platform:1.2.3"))

  // or import a platform from a local project
  implementation(platform(":my-project:version-platform"))


  // no need to define a version, if it's defined in the platform
  implementation("com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind")
}
```

This is the best of both worlds. Projects can be explicit about their dependencies, retain autonomy, while the versions can be aligned across independent projects.