# I'm getting this problem in the gradle build of my android studio/ionic build ( using angular)| Ionic capacitor run android

Tags: angular, gradle, ionic-framework

Basically i'm using ionic/gradle and android studio to emulate but it keeps giving this problem on the Vscode terminal. I should mention that i am using angular.

Terminal: Ionic capacitor run android

```
capacitor.cmd run android --target Pixel_2_API_30
[capacitor] √ Copying web assets from www to android\app\src\main\assets\public in 2.66s
[capacitor] √ Creating capacitor.config.json in android\app\src\main\assets in 1.94ms
[capacitor] [info] Inlining sourcemaps
[capacitor] √ copy android in 3.01s
[capacitor] √ Updating Android plugins in 15.82ms
[capacitor] [info] Found 4 Capacitor plugins for android:
[capacitor]        @capacitor/app@5.0.6
[capacitor]        @capacitor/haptics@5.0.6
[capacitor]        @capacitor/keyboard@5.0.6
[capacitor]        @capacitor/status-bar@5.0.6
[capacitor] √ update android in 134.47ms
[capacitor] × Running Gradle build - failed!
[capacitor] [error] 
[capacitor]         FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
[capacitor]
[capacitor]         * Where:
[capacitor]         Build file 'C:\Users\fjmor\ionic\lista\android\build.gradle' line: 2
[capacitor]
[capacitor]         * What went wrong:
[capacitor]         Could not compile build file 'C:\Users\fjmor\ionic\lista\android\build.gradle'.
[capacitor]         > startup failed:
[capacitor]         build file 'C:\Users\fjmor\ionic\lista\android\build.gradle': 2: Unexpected input: '{' @ line 2, column 13.
[capacitor]         allprojects {
[capacitor]         ^
[capacitor]
[capacitor]         1 error
[capacitor]
[capacitor]
[capacitor]         * Try:
[capacitor]         > Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
[capacitor]         > Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
[capacitor]         > Run with --scan to get full insights.
[capacitor]
[capacitor]         * Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
[capacitor]
[capacitor]         BUILD FAILED in 1s
[capacitor]
[ERROR] An error occurred while running subprocess capacitor.

        capacitor.cmd run android --target Pixel_2_API_30 exited with exit code 1.

        Re-running this command with the --verbose flag may provide more information.
```

h exit code 1.

```
    Re-running this command with the --verbose flag may provide more information.
```

Content of my build.gradle:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
buildscript {
    
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:8.0.2'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.15'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

apply from: "variables.gradle"

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

`

I've already tried to install a different version of gradle and java, but it did nothing...
Does someone know how do i fix this?

Answer (score 0):

The output indicates that there is a syntax error in your `build.gradle` file. I suggest looking at line 2 and seeing if it is indeed missing a bracket. If it looks right to you then try running `./gradlew clean` in the project directory in a terminal window or in Android Studio go to `Project > Clean Build Folder`. Then try rebuilding the project.

Comment: I tried but it appeared another error, i used the cmd to run the "gradlew clean" prompt, it ran but immediatly showed:   FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

Comment: Can you post the contents of your build.gradle file?

Comment: I edited the question and added my build.gradle content

Comment: The error is most likely coming from the line `apply from: "variables.gradle"`. It may just be as simple as changing to single quotations, but if not try following the instructions for referring to local files here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9539986/how-to-share-a-common-build-gradle-via-a-repository

Comment: I tried the single quotations and it didn't work, i forgot to mention that i was using angular. I will update the question and try to follow the instructions in the post you linked.